# bash - grep evaluating to true regardless of input

Tags: bash

I'm trying to index pdf files within a directory that match specific metadata but for some reason whether or not the string I'm looking for exists in my metadata variable my script will print every file name. In this case I'm taking the output of pdftk and searching for the string "InfoKey: Author", which I know some of my pdf's do not contain. However my script will spit back that every file contains it.

```
index() {
    for file in *
    do
        [ -d "$file" ] && (cd "$file"; index)

        if [ "$( echo "$file" | grep -E '.*\.pdf' )" ]; then
            metadata="$(pdftk "$file" dump_data)"
            [ -z $(grep -e '^InfoKey: Author' "$metadata" >/dev/null 2>&1) ] 
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$file"
            fi
        fi
    done
}


index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The elegance of `bash`

```
metadata="$(pdftk "$file" dump_data)"
[ -z $(grep -e '^InfoKey: Author' "$metadata" >/dev/null 2>&1) ] 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

`grep` searches through files. To get it to parse the output of `pdftk` you can't pass a string on the command-line because it'll treat it as a file name. Instead, use a pipe:

```
pdftk "$file" dump_data | grep -e '^InfoKey: Author' >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

The idiomatic way to write this is to put the command you're testing right into the `if` statement.

```
if pdftk "$file" dump_data | grep -e '^InfoKey: Author' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

You can then use `-q` to silence `grep`:

```
if pdftk "$file" dump_data | grep -qe '^InfoKey: Author'; then
    echo "$file"
fi
```

That's pretty good, no?

#### The power of `find`

Yes, perhaps. However, we can do better. Let's take a look at your recursive function. The most natural way to do recursive searches in bash is with `find`.

First, let's start with a basic `find` command which finds and prints all the `.pdf` files in the current directory or its sub-directories.

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -print
```

That's a good start. If you did nothing else, you could use this to replace the explicit recursion in your code. (Indeed, the next command I'm giving is rather nasty, so you might want to do that.) If you did, you could do something like:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' | while read file; do
    # process each $file
done
```

But anyways, onto the nasty—but awesome—`find` command which does everything in one fell swoop!

```
find . -name '*.pdf' \
    -exec sh -c 'pdftk "$1" dump_data | grep -qe "^InfoKey: Author"' -- {} \; \
    -print
```

This will recursively find all `.pdf` files. It then runs the `pdftk` pipeline as before.

The reason for the `sh` shell is to be able to do a pipeline with `-exec`. `-exec` only accepts a single command. To pass it a pipeline with two commands we need to add a layer of indirection. That's what the `sh` is. `-c` gives the command to run, and `{}` is the first argument to that command. `{}`, so you know, is a placeholder where `find` inserts the current file name. So the current file name is passed as the first argument to the `-c` command line. Inside that command, the file name shows up as `$1`.

Finally, if that entire command-line succeeds—if the `grep -q` successfully finds a match—then `find` executes the `-print` action, which prints the current file name.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! I was using find before but wasn't sure how to set it up to process the files the way I wanted because all the examples showed calling a specific bash command when using it.

Comment: In the interests of a (very slightly) shorter command, you can simply embed `{}` in place of `$1` rather than use `{}` as a positional argument.

Comment: @chepner File names with spaces would cause problems if you did.

Comment: `sh -c 'pdftk "{}" ...'` should work fine for a filename containing whitespace.

Comment: @chepner What about one with double quotes, or dollar signs, etc.?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Touché. Those would cause problems with my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You're not testing the status of `bash`, you're testing the status of `[` (aka `test`), which is testing whether the output is empty (which it always is because you redirected the output). Also, you're using `$metadata` as a filename argument to `grep`; if you want to test its contents, you need to pipe it to the command:

```
    if [ "$( echo "$file" | grep -E '.*\.pdf' )" ]; then
        metadata="$(pdftk "$file" dump_data)"
        echo "$metadata" | grep -e '^InfoKey: Author' >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "$file"
        fi
    fi
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried what you had for an answer before but with [] around it and was still getting the issue I described before but this worked perfectly